# How can I get twitter running on my local server?

Tags: twitter

I want to put the Twitter service on my server and customize it for my purpose. I have no idea how it works.

My goal is to communicate to your own Twitter server rather than the original twitter server and serve my purpose.

Comment: Twitter doesn't do this. You'll have to make your own site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should check out: [StatusNet](http://status.net/).  It is an open source micro blogging platform.  From their site, you can download the source and deploy it on your own server.  Once you have it installed you can customize it to your liking.

Answer (score 6):

Twitter isn't an Open Source project - they don't provide their server code.

From my experience at another company deploying very widely distributed systems, the chances are there's a bucket-load of infrastructure you'd need to get running first - complete overkill for a single-server solution, but vital for a global service with many millions of users. In other words, even if Twitter *did* provide their code, it probably wouldn't be an appropriate solution for your situation.

Comment: If i recall correctly, i heard somewhere that twitter rebuilt their code every time they had a large amount of growth because their previous solution didn't work. Or maybe it was Facebook or Myspace...

Comment: That would be entirely sensible. A solution which works for n * 100 users is usually inappropriate for n users.

Answer (score 2):

The actual Twitter ([twitter.com](http://twitter.com)) service is proprietary, you can't run it yourself.

There are plenty of open source twitter clones out there. The more general name is "microblogging". [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) for example has basic microblogging. Try searching google for '[open source microblogging](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=open+source+microblogging)' for other projects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the Twitter platform is freely available to the general public.  If you want to make your own "Twitter server", you're going to have to clone the service yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Twitter on your own server, but you can write your own application that talks to Twitter through [Twitter's API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/).

It all depends on what you mean by "customizing" Twitter. There are many applications like [Twitpic](http://twitpic.com/) and [TweetDeck](http://tweetdeck.com/) that are built "on top of" Twitter. They add their own functionality while leaving Twitter to do the "heavy lifting".

For example, I have written a personal project for moderating a stream of tweets. This application runs on my local server, but it gets its data by querying Twitter's API.

There are two main advantages to extending rather than rebuilding Twitter:

- It takes a lot less effort because you can reuse all the basic functions of Twitter
- You can take advantage of Twitter's huge user base. Even if you succeeded in cloning Twitter, it would be far less interesting than the original because Twitter works by strength of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Wordpress and get the twitter developer add in then get a api code from them and there users can use your site and vice versa also apps for twitter will work for your site.

Comment: Good of you to jump in and help, but notice that this question was asked and answered two and a half years ago. Also, if you read the question carefully, you'll see that the original poster doesn't want to use Twitter itself, but rather a similar service on his/her own server. Finally, you will gain more traction on this site if you type in full words, complete sentences, and use a more grwon-up username than "Poop Face".

Answer (score -1):

Wow. That's a highly ambitious request that you have there. Twitter isn't like Wordpress, there's no .org version that can be downloaded and run locally. Twitter is a highly scalable service that is designed to run on large scale servers.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news to you on this.