# Twitter Threading Script

Tags: multithreading, twitter, open-source

Is there a free open source Twitter Threading script/platform?

Comment: A threading what? Twitter client? Or a microblogging service that works like twitter? If you want to create a twitter-like service see this question asked a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452069/how-can-i-make-the-twitter-running-on-my-local-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for: [Threaded Convo Script](http://www.twitterscripts.net/threadconvo.php).

Comment: It's not free, but it's *cheap* and looks good.

Comment: Question was asked 12 years ago but again I need answer for this. the link has been removed from twitterscripts.net